# Pinia store issue with Vite + Vue + Vuetify project

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, pinia, vuetifyjs3

Actually we have the requirement of migrating from Vue-2 to Vue-3. In our existing project we were using the stack like,

- Vue - 2.x version
- Vuetify - 2.x version
- Javascript

While trying to migrate from Vue-2 to Vue-3, we choose the stack like,

- Vue - 3.x version
- Vuetify - 3.x version
- Typescript

We have successfully converted the vue-2 project login and landing page components into vue-3 after lot of struggles but finally end up with a problem of state/store management of application components because we haven't used the PINIA. We have implemented the basis store which was bit similar to vue-2 supported and later found an issue of resetting the global values when application is getting refreshed or reloaded.

I came to know after investigating about the problem and found Pinia is the better library to solve my problem because Vuex-4 is out of the date. I found a POC project which is implemented using the [PINIA + Vue-3 POC](https://github.com/Nallamachu/vue-3-pinia-registration-login-example). Since I am not able to mention the entire project source code, I shared the link.

Here multiple problems I need to mention,

1. When I try to install Vuetify in the above poc project, application is not working as expected and not loading the components properly.
2. When I try to follow the similar implementation of PINIA stores in Vue-3 + Vuetify-3 converted project, getting the problem of **getActivePinia() was called with no active pinia** issue.
   [image]

Store usage in login page look like below,
[image]

I have tried couple of solutions suggested for getActivePinia was called with no active pinia problem and could not succeed as of now. If someone can help me with the example of Vue3 + Vuetify3 + Pinia + Typescript with proper store/state management will be more helpful.

Comment: First of all, do not post images of code. Post the relevant code instead. Please read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1891677). Second of all, it sounds like you haven't added (in some shape or form) a `.use(createPinia())` to you `app`, in `main.js` (or `.ts`). From what you posted so far, your question cannot be answered.

Comment: @tao, Kindly go through the link which is pointing to github POC. Since I can't place the complete code in this question, given an alternative. I am not sure where exactly you have found that createPinia() is not used in app. Look at this one, https://github.com/Nallamachu/vue-3-pinia-registration-login-example/blob/master/src/main.js

Comment: @tao My actual project is in VDI, and I can't move the code from VDI to local and vice versa.

Comment: So let me see if I got this right: you took a tutorial project which works anywhere, including on your local and installed it in a virtual container which you can't share, where it doesn't work. Correct? I'd say your only option is to contact whoever is providing you the VDI solution. Fingers crossed!

Comment: Yes, you are correct and I agree with you. If you observe in POC, every script tag has setup keyword. If I try to use the same in my project with defineComponent and all not accepting to use. any suggestion for that. If I haven't use setup, pinia is not getting identified whichever I have created in main.ts

Comment: I made a POC for Vue3+Vuetify3+Vite+PINIA technologies. This might be helpful for someone else. https://github.com/Nallamachu/vue3-vuetify3-pinia-vite

Answer (score 0):

I have finally got a proper solution and able to integrate in real-time project of [Pinia State/Store management](https://github.com/Nallamachu/vue3-vuetify3-pinia-vite).

Since no one is able to answer the question, I am posting my POC project link here. This might be helpful to someone else who is having the requirement of same.

[POC Project of Pinia with Vue3 + Vuetify 3 + Vite](https://github.com/Nallamachu/vue3-vuetify3-pinia-vite)